# How to merge pandas.core.series.Series and numpy.int32 to pandas.core.frame.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df, On this data, I build some clustering model, and found the labels, the labels I get as an array, now I need the merge the data and labels

```
data = [['M', 10, 'red','apple'], 
        ['F', 15, 'blue','orange'], 
        ['M', 14, 'blue','apple'],
        ['M', 14, 'blue','apple'], 
        ['F', 14, 'blue','apple'], 
        ['M', 14, 'red',''], 
        ['M', 14, 'blue','banana'], 
        ['', 14, 'blue','apple']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Gender', 'Age', 'Color','Fruit'])
```

df is encoded as numbers, then, the labels is get as

```
df_encode = OneHotEncoder(df)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters= 2)
kmeans.fit(df_encode.values)
labels = kmeans.labels_
type(labels)
Out[120]: numpy.ndarray
labels
Out[122]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

i view both of them as follows

```
for i in range(len(df_encode)):
    print("coordinate:",df_encode.iloc[i], "label:", labels[i])
```

This gives output like

```
coordinate: 
Gender      1.0
Age        10.0
Color       0.0
Fruit       1.0
label: 0
```

Here how should I merge label as a column in df_encode dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn it to a list and attach it to your dataframe:

```
kmf2labels = labels.tolist()
df_encode['labels'] = kmf2labels
```

Output:

```
df_encode['labels']
Out[39]: 
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
Name: labels, dtype: int64
```